# What is the name of the chemical Sulfur or Sulphur?

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Is the chemical Sulfur or Sulphur?

Answer (score 4):

***Sulfur vs. sulphur***; the spelling difference is mainly a question of AmE vs other English speaking countries  as suggested by the [Grammarist:](http://grammarist.com/spelling/sulfur-sulphur/)

> - For the pale yellow nonmetallic element found especially in volcanic deposits, ***sulfur is the usual spelling in American English***.
> - ***Sulphur is generally the preferred spelling in nonscientific texts from outside North America***, but sulfur is gaining ground in scientific writing throughout the English-speaking world
> - The spelling distinction extends to derivative words such as sulfuric/sulphuric, sulfate/sulphate, and sulfide/sulphide.

Etymology:

> - Usually English words spelled with '*ph*' are derived from Greek, where the '*ph*' represents the Greek letter ‘phi’, ***but in this case the ultimate source of the word is Arabic.***
> - The word, from the French soufre, entered English around the end of the 14th century. Both modern spellings have been in use for many centuries, but ***sulphur prevailed by a wide margin until the Americans adopted sulfur around the start of the 20th century*** as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sulfur%2C%20sulphur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csulfur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csulphur%3B%2Cc0).

It is interesting to note that:

> - ***[The International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry) did indeed officially adopt the sulfur spelling in 1990; in 1992 [the Royal Society of Chemistry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Society_of_Chemistry) followed suit,*** issuing a press release adopting sulfur as the official international nomenclature for atomic element 16.
> - But while this might seem to settle the case once and for all, it’s clear that not all practising scientists have adopted the spelling change.  This is a good example of the difficulties of reforming established spellings, even in a relatively defined group of users.

([spellingtrouble.blogspot.it](http://spellingtrouble.blogspot.it/2013/02/sulphur-or-sulfur.html))

Comment: There was a farcical situation in the UK for a time when candidates would lose a mark for the spelling _sulphur_ in chemistry and for the spelling _sulfur_ in English exams.